# How can I open a Data URI in an external browser using Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, data-uri

I am working on an Android project using Jetpack Compose. I am attempting to open a Data URI in an external browser using the `LocalUriHandler`, but I always encounter a runtime error.

This is my current code:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalUriHandler

val dataUri = "data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PGgxPkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCE8L2gxPjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+"

val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current
uriHandler.openUri("dataUri")
```

It works perfectly fine using a URL such as "https://www.google.com", but when using a Data URI, it leads to the following exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=data: }
```

I would highly appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: You probably need some kind of valid URI to make it work. You might be able to save it to a file and send it a `file://` location.

Comment: You could try to open this URL into ```Webview```